# How can I retroactively tag friends in a post on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-tags

I posted a status update on Facebook and tagged a few friends in it, but I forgot one, and another only accepted my friend request *after* I had already posted the status update. How can I now retroactively tag the other friends in my status update?

[image: Tag Friends]

When I click on `Tag Friends`, I get a list of all the friends I have already tagged in that post. However, there is no way to *add* new ones.

[image: Selected]

If I select `Selected` from the dropdown menu, I get a list of only the currently selected friends. I can *unselect* friends from this list, which presumable will untag them, but I cannot add new ones.

[image: Search by Name]

If I select `Search by Name`, I can try to enter a name into the text field titled `Search all friends`, but it *doesn't* search all friends, it again only searches amongst those that I have already selected. Friends which are not already tagged in the post, simply don't show up.

I also tried using the Facebook for Android App, but there doesn't seem to be any way to tag friends either.

Do I have to use the API for this? I feel quite comfortable with `curl` and friends, so it wouldn't be a big problem, but I am not familiar with the API nor the API docs, so I wasn't able to find the right endpoint at a quick glance.

I know that it used to be possible to tag friends in posts after the fact, and I know that it still works with photos. How can I tag someone in a post after the fact, using either the website, the Android App or the API?

I originally posted the status update from the Android App, if that makes a difference. Also, I am using the German language version of both the website and the App, although as you can see from the screenshots, I tried switching at least the website to en-US and it didn't help.

Comment: This is working for me. There must be some problem with your account. Try to click on 'v' on upper right side on post and click on 'tag friends' from dropdown menu. You will get the same pop-up as you have added screenshot and you will see all your friends and you can search by name aslo.

Comment: The `v` dropdown menu was added *years* after I asked this question. Considering the rate at which Facebook deploys updates, there must have been literally a *thousand* versions between when I tried this and now, including at least two major design updates. It does indeed work now, at least for *some* posts, but I guess it has more to do with one of those thousand updates fixing a bug than with there being something wrong with my account.

Comment: Wait. Actually, now that I read my question again, I say there right in the question that it works for photos but not for some other kind of posts. And indeed, that's *still* the case: I can tag and untag friends after the fact from photos and videos (e.g. https://facebook.com/Joerg.Mittag/videos/978477082229945/ and https://facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=960311857379801), but not from "normal" status updates (e.g. https://facebook.com/Joerg.Mittag/posts/984688844942102) or some other kinds (e.g. https://facebook.com/Joerg.Mittag/posts/984869188257401 what do you call those?).

Comment: It *does*, however, work now for the post that this question is about: https://facebook.com/Joerg.Mittag/posts/405054686238857 . Unfortunately, I forgot whom I wanted to tag :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, sometime within the last three years, Facebook either fixed a bug or added a feature that makes this work (again?), at least for the post that this question was originally about.

Unfortunately, there are still some posts for which the menu doesn't even appear, however, when it *does* appear, it also *does* work, unlike three years ago, when I wrote this question.

So, I consider this a bug which existed back then, and has been fixed in the meantime, and thus I consider this question answered.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is good enough for your use case, but I guess you could always add extra tagged people in a comment on the original post.