# In Facebook, is there anyway to add / tag a person in a post after you have posted?

Tags: facebook, facebook-tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I retroactively tag friends in a post on Facebook?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/35589/how-can-i-retroactively-tag-friends-in-a-post-on-facebook)

Is there any way in Facebook to add a person to a post after you have already posted.  I see you can tag a picture after the fact but I can't seem to find out how to do that with a regular status post.

Comment: can't you edit the status? if yes, then you can add also

Comment: @Anusha - that is what i am asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, there is no known functionality (for now) which allows you to edit your status and who you're with (that's the name for tagging someone in a status). You can, anyway, add a location or change the date. As [Anusha](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/22420/anusha) suggested, you can do that in the comments by tagging a friend. Type @Foo to tag your friend Foo.

Answer (score 2):

Previously, Facebook used to edit status but not comments. And the recent updates in Facebook is - you cant edit status but you can edit your comment. :)

Now, what you can do is - Post a comment on your status and type '@' and then start typing the name of that person. It will automatically show you the list of related names. Then you can select the name to tag. This is equal to tagging and will notify the opposite person also.

For example, if you start typing as `A` it will show you `Anusha` if Anusha is your friend :)